# nginx refuses to connect to wordpress

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress

I have an nginx 1.15.3 server on ubuntu 18.04 LTS that I'm trying to serve content being either a webpage or videos using various plugins on my wordpress site which is on a different server/IP entirely. However, when I try to use an advanced iframe module on that website to pull a webpage that just has a video stream on it(it worked here: http://www.tinywebgallery.com/blog/advanced-iframe/free-iframe-checker), it says that the IP of the nginx server refused to connect and this also goes for any other kind of connection I try to make or if I try to pull any of the video streams I need. Whatever is going on has to do with how nginx is interacting with wordpress or vice versa, I'm really not sure. The wordpress version on the other server is 4.9.8 so everything should be up to date.

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
    chunk_size 4096;

    application show1 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls1/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show2 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls2/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show3 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls3/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show4 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls4/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show5 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls5/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show6 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls6/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show7 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls7/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
    application cam01 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam02 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam03 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam04 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam05 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam06 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam07 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
}
}

http {
sendfile off;
tcp_nopush on;
default_type application/octet-stream;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        # Disable cache
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /mnt/;
        location /index.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
        location /testing.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
        location /test.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam01.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam02.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam03.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam04.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam05.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam06.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam07.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm still pretty new to wordpress, nginx, and serverfault, so if any more information is needed, feel free to ask and I will provide. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is nothing in your given nginx configuration which would serve WordPress. Start with a sample configuration from wordpress.org and go from there.

Comment: I'm not hosting wordpress on this server though, the wordpress is on another server and it's calling things like the cam01.html page or the streams over the internet which are already set up in the config. Do I have to have something in the config to specifically have wordpress pull these elements then even if they're already set up in the config? Just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: OK, then much of your question makes no sense. Try to cut out anything irrelevant and simplify it to the minimum specific problem.

Comment: How does it not make sense? I was detailing how wordpress can't pull any kind of webpage or video stream from nginx, but when I try to load a webpage from the server on a browser, from the iframe tester I linked, or pull a video stream via VLC over the internet, nginx doesn't refuse to connect. I went into detail in the post (since that's generally encouraged I thought), but that's what my issue is on a most basic level.

Comment: Well, first, you keep using the word "pull" to describe something, but it's not clear what exactly you mean by that word. Try using standard English and technical terms instead of local jargon which is not likely to be understood outside your organization.

Comment: I tried simplifying the question as much as I could and replaced "pull" with serve content, I really don't know how to specify better than that, I'm just trying to understand why nginx keeps refusing to connect to an entirely separate wordpress setup when everything else works fine when connecting to nginx.

Comment: That also doesn't make sense. Your nginx is not configured to connect to anywhere else. So it's not clear why you expect it to make any connection.

Comment: When I go to one of the html pages or have VLC connect to one of the active rtmp or hls streams, it works just fine. My question is why can't wordpress also do that so that it can re-display the content on a wordpress site when you can connect to the nginx server with no issue over the internet otherwise. Nginx is just hosting streams and html pages and it is working on it's own and you can connect to it just fine on it's own, it's only wordpress that's having any issue right now in terms of seeing what content nginx is serving already that I can verify it is serving.

Comment: Let me try re-explaining this in a broader sense, why can't wordpress access content from my website I'm hosting over the internet that uses nginx? I think nginx refuses to communicate to this completely different server that uses wordpress, but I don't know.

Comment: So the entire nginx configuration you've shown so far actually works perfectly?! OK, show us something that doesn't work. It doesn't make sense when you say "why can't wordpress access content from my website". How is WordPress supposed to be doing this? What plugin is loading the content? How did you configure it?

Comment: Wordpress is using an iframe, iframes can repost parts of or entire webpages if you specify the webpage in the html on a page that's hosted on another server using, let's say, wordpress. When I specify a webpage that is through the nginx server I have that's on the internet, the nginx server refuses to connect to my wordpress site and will not serve any of the content I ask for from an iframe since nginx refuses to connect.

Comment: That's why I mentioned using standard English. WordPress doesn't "access" anything in that scenario. And nginx doesn't "connect" to WordPress. The web browser does the accessing and the connecting. I suggest you look for errors in your browser's console.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying, hope I didn't seem confrontational, was just trying to figure out how to get you to understand, thank you for being patient too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so taking the advice of Michael Hampton to inspect the web console for errors on the webpage. I found that nginx is serving everything through http and not https while I was requesting the wordpress site in https causing a mixed content error of some kind probably not helped by how I use https everywhere. Requesting the webpage in regular http lets the content load normally. Thanks for the help!